# How to get updates while Running an Android App with DJI MSDK while minimized?

Tags: android, kotlin, dji-sdk

I have an app, using DJI MSDK. I am using

```
KeyManager.getInstance().listen(myKey, this) {                      // listen to flight controller location key
    oldV,newV ->
// do my things

// check the value of newV (NewV does not update while minimized)
// talk to a server (THIS works)

}
```

This is packed inside a function, which is inside a runnable.

This works, no issue.

But once the app is minimized or loses focus, the listener does not send any further update.I am using DJI MSDK V5.7. Ho

What can I do, so that the listener keeps on sending values, even when the app loses focus or is minimized?

I understand, that I may have to bring this to a foreground service. However, I am very confused. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067352/running-a-foreground-service-in-android-kotlin-to-show-notifications-every-minut) to guide me.

However, I need a step by step guide in how to

- Declare the forground actions in manifest for DJI MSDK
- Get permissions to run DJI MSDK in foreground
- Send the runnable to a foreground action

Thank you