# How do I bring a runnable to foreground?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is an extension of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876079/how-to-get-updates-while-running-an-android-app-with-dji-msdk-while-minimized). It appears, that I would need to periodically (at 10HZ) send my runnable to the foreground.

I have read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@hellokhorshed/using-foreground-service-in-android-69faa5dfa3e). I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067352/running-a-foreground-service-in-android-kotlin-to-show-notifications-every-minut).

Basically, I have a runnable in my app, that calls functions, which in turn call several other API functions.

```
val telemetryRunnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {

        pollValues() // This disconnects the connection between android and an external device when in background

        if (!connOn) return

        submitReport()// this calls a WebSocket server, and this works even in background

        telemetryHandler.postDelayed(this, 100) // Check every 1/10 seconds
    }
}
```

I need to pack this runnable without much problem in a foreground service. I dont want to change anything in the API or the functions that call them. I need something like:

```
useMagic(telemetryRunnable);
```

to ensure that the runnable is executed in the foreground even if the app is in the background. How would I go about it? Thank you.

Comment: Foreground service just makes less chance your app will be killed by the system. Apart from that you probably need to acquire a CPU wake lock, but be aware it will be draining the battery.

Comment: Regarding where to "pack your runnable", you can move related code to the service and start the runnable in service's onCreate method.